# jQuery UI: Action when slider position changes

Tags: jquery, user-interface, uislider

I am using this jQuery UI slider from http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps
It's a simple slider with 3 steps (1, 2 and 3) and a div-element ("id_1") that shows a picture. So what I actually want now is that the picture changes depending on the position of the slider. So in position "1" it shows a picture, and this picture changes as soon as i move the slider to position 2 or 3. How can i do this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Slider - Snap to increments</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 1,
            max: 3,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<label for="amount">Donation amount ($50 increments):</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="id_1" class="class_1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to look at the value of the slider, and then show the appropriate image. Try something like this:

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.value == 1) {
                $("#id_1")).attr("src", "image1.png");
            } else  if (ui.value == 2) {
                $("#id_1")).attr("src", "image2.png");
            } else  if (ui.value == 3) {
                $("#id_1")).attr("src", "image3.png");
            }
        }
```

And make the id_1 div an img tag instead:

```
<img id="id_1" class="class_1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! the ui.value thing was exactly what I needed. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wx2MT/) (It's a fiddle).

I created an array which holds the images you need like this

```
var images = [
"http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg",
"http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg",
"http://oddanimals.com/images/lime-cat.jpg"
]; // replace these links with the ones pointing to your images
```

Then, when the slider moves

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
            $("#id_1").html("<img src=\"" + images[ui.value-1] + "\" />"); // subtracting 1 as the arrays first index is 0
        }
```

And finalize it by loading the first image of the array when the page loads

```
 $("#id_1").html("<img src=\"" + images[0] + "\" />"); // Load the first image on page load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in slide event only.

```
     <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({
                value: 100,
                min: 1,
                max: 3,
                step: 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
if(ui.value == 1)
{
    $('#imgSource').attr('src','1.png');
}
else if(ui.value == 2)
    {
        $('#imgSource').attr('src','2.png');
    }

                }
            });
            $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just add one img with id imgSource in Div.